# Show that for any positive integer $m$ there are $m$ consecutive positive integers each of which has at least $10$ positive divisors.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In other words, show that for any positive integer $m$ there are $m$ consecutive positive integers $a+1, a+2, ..., a+m$ such that $τ(a + i) ≥ 10$ for each $i = 1, 2, ..., m)$

I don't think i even understood the question, let alone solve it. Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n=p_1^4p_2$ (product of prime p0wers), then $\tau(n)=10$.

So let us consider a sequence of numbers $N_1, N_2, N_3, \ldots $ such that $N_k=p_{1k}^4p_{2k}$, where $p_{1k}, p_{2k}$ are distinct primes in increasing order for all $k \geq 1$ (i.e. $p_{11}<p_{21}<p_{12}<p_{22}<\dotsb$). Then $\gcd(N_i,N_j)=1$ for $i \neq j$.

Now we want to find a number $a$ such that
\begin{align*}
a& \equiv -1 \pmod{N_1}\\
a& \equiv -2 \pmod{N_2}\\
a& \equiv -3 \pmod{N_3}\\
\vdots & \equiv \vdots\\
a& \equiv -m \pmod{N_m}.
\end{align*}
Since the $N_i's$ are pairwise relatively prime so we can apply Chinese Remainder Theorem to guarantee that such an $a$ exists.

Now consider $a+1, a+2, a+3, ...$. This is a sequence of consecutive integers, each of which is divisible by a number $N_i$ that has exactly $10$ positive divisors.

*Note:* If you want more positive divisors than $10$, then just increase the power of one of the primes in $N_i$.

Comment: Alright, i get that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime. What can you say about the system of congruences $N \equiv -k \mod p_n^9$ for $1\le k \le m$? What can you say about a solution to the system?

Once you answer these questions, you will have solved the problem.

Comment: Sounds like chinese remainder but i still have no idea, i am sorry

Comment: Wouah, it's a nice way to use the chinese remainders theorem ^^